# USB 3.0 expansion card instability

Tags: linux-mint, usb

I am running Linux mint Vera (21.1) on a somewhat old computer motherboard (2013), ASROck H61M-VG3, where I have no USB 3.0 port.

Thus, I decided to buy a USB 3.0 expansion card  (PCIe x1) I plugged the card into PCIe x1 slot (which is advertised to be sufficient to power the 4 connectors), but just to be safe in the safe side I also plugged the molex adapter.

When I plug a USB device on the USB 3.0 port it gets powered, but there are stability issues: my mouse work for some seconds then stop, my RGB keyboard light is on but when pressing button there are no input my USB wireless adapter get laggy and timeout like interrupt browsing on the internet (TIME OUT).

Here is my `lspci`:

```
01:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805/806 xHCI USB 3.0 Controller (rev 01)
```

I have read somewhere on the internet about firmware update or grub config?

Comment: "I have read somewhere": please link to that source. It seems to be plain wrong (GRUB has nothing to do with this, and VIA has never published firmware updates for their PCIe-USB3 controllers of the first generation as far as I'm aware), and all you describe just points to hardware problems that Linux can't really do anything about.

Comment: by the way, neither a mouse nor a keyboard use USB3, at all (or at least, I've never seen a USB3 HID device – it makes no sense. A mouse needs to transfer maybe 1000 bits per second, not more than 480 million bits per second, so USB1 suffices, USB 2 is plenty, and USB 3 just makes the mouse more expensive, power hungry, complicated… So just don't connect your input devices to your USB3 card)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I cited the keyboard and mouse because it's with them that i tried to troubleshoot the problem before buying a USB 3.0 flash drive or a netgear a8000 wifi adapter

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem lately, but with a different card model.
It was recognized by the kernel, but simply would not connect anything.
After trying a lot of things with the kernel module parameters, restarting, etc. the solution turned out to be as simple as to unplug and re-plug the card.
Especially on older systems, the connectors might simply have a bad connection.